# Non-friends interacting with Facebook account

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to see if non-friends are interacting with profile or Facebook account?

Comment: What you mean by interacting with profile or Facebook account? How do you know when friends interact with profile?

Comment: What I mean is there a way to track how many people look at it through apps, for example.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, there is no official way to check who has visited or viewed your Facebook profile.

There is a Chrome extension called “Profile Visitors for Facebook”, install it and restart Chrome, open your Facebook account, you will find a new Tab as “Visitors”, there you can find all the viewers who viewed your profile.<sup>[1]</sup>

Don't trust on any site or app who tell that "See Who Viewed Your Profile", they are fake and phishing sites/apps and can hack your profile or steal your data by asking so many permissions.

<sup>[1]:I have not used this extension. Use at your own risk.</sup>